# Can't catch Exception thrown by Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

The following code throws an exception that I can't catch for whatever reason.

```
try {
    $this->date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->date)->toDateString();
}
catch (Exception $err) {
    $this->date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse("January 1st 1900")->toDateString();
}
```

Now, if I put this in my routes file in a function closure, it works fine. It's only throwing an exception when it's called from the Model.

`exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Summer 2015) at position 0 (S): The timezone could not be found in the database' in /home/vagrant/www/steamcompare/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php:222`

Has anyone else had this issue with Carbon?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Immediately after posing the question, I thought of the answer. Since I saw a lot of posts online about a very similar issue, I figured I'd go ahead and answer this one.

The issue was namespacing. Carbon was running in a different namespace from my app (obviously) so when I tried to `catch (Exception)` I was actually trying to catch an exception within my app's namespace. Changing the catch statement to `catch (\Exception)` resolved it.

I hope this helps anyone that ends up on this page.

Comment: You should mark your answer as the correct answer while you're here answering your question :)

Comment: I will, once the timer that SO puts on a question goes away.

Comment: Ahh sorry didn't realise there was one.

Comment: No worries, you have to wait 48 hours before you can accept your own answer. =/

Comment: I suppose it's there to stop people artificially upping their score by asking and answering their own questions loads and loads.

Comment: One frickin' backslash …

Comment: @alexrussell i don't know, you can actually even post "question" with "answer" type of post on stackoverflow. it can't be for score neither, because it is really trivial to figure out whether has the question been answered by the original author. plus, you can even answer it later

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Carbon::parse generates PHP warnings, so you cannot catch it using try .. catch

Comment: @realtebo this is a 7 year old post and the provided solution DID work. If it no longer works that would be due to changes in Carbon.