# Laravel : Can't catch exception thrown by Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

Below code throws an fatal error but I can't catch for whatever reason.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Log;

public function testError()
    {
        try {

            $now                         = Carbon::now();
            $datetime = null;
            //$datetime = Carbon::parse($datetime);
            $lastlock = $datetime->diffInSeconds($now);
            Log::info($lastlock);
            //
        }catch (\Exception $d){
            Log::info("error:: " . $d->getMessage());

        } 
    }
```

Its throwing an fatal error

```
FatalErrorException in TestController.php line 310:
Call to a member function diffInSeconds() on null
```

I want it should be handle in catch block.

Please suggest.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/31248584/296555

Comment: @waterloomatt The OP is using the "solution" or the linked question where he is using the correct namespace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't catch symfony FatalErrorException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406566/cant-catch-symfony-fatalerrorexception)

Comment: @NicoHaase, its not duplicate, here namespace proper, want to know the reason why catch don't handle it

Answer (score 1):

use Throwable instead of Exception

```
try {

        $now                         = Carbon::now();
        $datetime = null;
        //$datetime = Carbon::parse($datetime);
        $lastlock = $datetime->diffInSeconds($now);
        Log::info($lastlock);
        //
    }catch (\Throwable $d){
        Log::info("error:: " . $d->getMessage());

    }
```

**UPDATE**

It seems php 5 handles exceptions differently and I am using php 7.2

Try this:

```
 try {
     $now                         = Carbon::now();
        $datetime = null;
        //$datetime = Carbon::parse($datetime);
        $lastlock = $datetime->diffInSeconds($now);
        Log::info($lastlock);
        //
} catch(Error $e) {
    dd($e->getMessage());
} catch(Throwable $e) {
    dd($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Hmm that's weird, I just tried it locally it it worked perfectly

Comment: @AshishChaturvedi Try to import the class in your controller: use Throwable; and then remove the backslash in the catch does that work?

Comment: use Throwable class and removed the backslash from catch block. same error exists. i am using PHP 5.6.36-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)

Comment: @AshishChaturvedi I have updated my answer, try that, also try adding the \ infront of Error if it doesn't work right away, Not sure if you're able to reach it by default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177575/discussion-between-ashish-chaturvedi-and-killstreet).